# Custom List View to display VF Page

Tags: visualforce, list-view

Is it possible to display a VF page for a custom list view ?

[image]

From the above, instead of those list columns I want to render a VF page containing a list of cases.

Comment: How about [apex:enhancedList](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have a few options, you could use an `apex:enhancedList` on your Visualforce page, which is covered in the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm).

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:enhancedList type="Case" height="300" rowsPerPage="10" id="YourListViewId" />
</apex:page>
```

---

Alternatively you can use a [Standard List Controller](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_sosc_about.htm) (with an `apex:repeat`, `apex:dataTable` or `apex:pageBlockTable` and set the `fcf` parameter in your URL to the desired List View ID.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetVar="cases">
    <apex:repeat value="{!cases}" var="c">
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.Id}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Then navigate to the page using a URL similar to this:
`http://yourinstance.salesforce.com/apex/YourListPage?fcf=YourListViewId`

---

Finally, you can use a StandardSetController within a Custom Controller and set the desired ListView in Apex using `setFilterID`, which is covered in the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_setFilterID.htm).

```
<apex:page controller="CaseList">
    <apex:repeat value="{!cases}" var="c">
        <apex:outputText value="{!c.Id}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Then your Controller will look something like this:

```
public class CaseList
{
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc;

    public CaseList
    {
        List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Name FROM Case];

        ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(caseList);
        ssc.setFilterID(YourFilterId);
    }

    public List<Case> getCases() 
    {
        return (List<Case>)ssc.getRecords();
    }
}
```